# AngularJS: Use ng-repeat to dynamically load CSS stylesheets

Tags: html, css, angularjs, header, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've split up my stylesheets into a separate module for each include, I want to dynamically load these but am having some dificulity, when rendered I only get the following for each sheet that should be loaded:

```
<link ng-repeat="inlude in includes" rel="stylesheet" href="" class="ng-scope">
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="forum" ng-controller="masterCtrl">
<head>
    <title>Forum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link ng-repeat="inlude in includes" rel="stylesheet" href="{{include.stylesheet}}">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my primary controller:

```
function masterCtrl($scope){
    $scope.includes = {
        header: {
            src: 'views/includes/header.html',
            stylesheet: 'stylesheets/header.css',
            searchQuery: ''
        },
        threadList: {
            src: 'views/includes/threadList.html',
            stylesheet: 'stylesheets/threadList.css'
        }
    };
}
```

Everything else works fine, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of changing your `href` to `ng-href`, revise your link like below, because you're not setting a source for the stylesheets.

```
<link ng-repeat="include in includes" rel="stylesheet" ng-href="include.stylesheet" class="ng-scope">
```

P.S. It wasn't working because you had a typo with include — `inlude in includes`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your href attributes with [ng-href](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref) attributes.  That approach won't be great for the speed of your page, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [AngularCSS](https://github.com/door3/angular-css)

This Angular module allows you to reference stylesheets in your components (directives) and pages (routes).

If you are using directives

```
myApp.directive('miyDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-directive/my-directive.html',
    css: 'my-directive/my-directive.css'
  }
});
```

If you are using ngRoute

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/my-page', {
    templateUrl: 'my-page/my-page.html',
    controller: 'pageCtrl',
    css: 'my-page/my-page.css'
  });
```

You can also use it as a service ($css)

```
myApp.controller('pageCtrl', function ($scope, $css) {

  // Binds stylesheet(s) to scope create/destroy events (recommended over add/remove)
  $css.bind({ 
    href: 'my-page/my-page.css'
  }, $scope);

  // Simply add stylesheet(s)
  $css.add('my-page/my-page.css');

  // Simply remove stylesheet(s)
  $css.remove(['my-page/my-page.css','my-page/my-page2.css']);

  // Remove all stylesheets
  $css.removeAll();

});
```